# Python asterisk ami

Tags: python, asterisk

Im trying to implement a simple call generator using asterisk ami interface.
I used astersik-ami package, there was no issue connecting and sending command to asterisk but i have hard time to make the code receive AMI events from asterisk.
I made a very simple test code which yet does not receive asterisk events.
I have verified using tcpdump that asterisk is sending events to ami client but whatever i do the ami client does not get the event using builtin ami library handler
python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
from asterisk.ami import AMIClient, SimpleAction,EventListener


# Asterisk AMI configuration
ami_host = '127.0.0.1'
ami_port = 5038
ami_username = 'testuser'
ami_password = '123456'


# Create Asterisk AMI client
ami = AMIClient(address=ami_host, port=ami_port)
ami.login(username=ami_username, secret=ami_password)


class AllEventListener(EventListener):

    def on_event(self,event, **kwargs):
        print('Event', event)


ami.add_event_listener(AllEventListener())

while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Stop the processing thread and wait for it to finish
        terminate_flag = True
        #processing_thread.join()
        break

# Cleanup
ami.logoff()
```

i also tried the following method which can not get to work also:

```
def event_listener(event,**kwargs):
    print('called')
    print(event)
    print(**kwargs)

ami.add_event_listener(event_listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your event listener is not the same as in example for that library

https://github.com/ettoreleandrotognoli/python-ami/blob/master/examples/simple_event_notification.py

```
def event_notification(source, event):
```

Comment: Also you must turn the events on. Check the [Event action](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+18+ManagerAction_Events)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there has been some changes in the library timeout attribute.
The class should be instantiate this way as a work around :

```
ami = AMIClient(address=ami_host, port=ami_port,timeout=None)
```